# VSCode debugger try to import modules from unusual place

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

I try to run my python code in the debugging mode, but got an error with message:

```
Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/.local/lib/python3.10'
  File "/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/anaconda3/envs/inst_crawl/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 431, in _joinrealpath
    st = os.lstat(newpath)
  File "/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/anaconda3/envs/inst_crawl/lib/python3.10/posixpath.py", line 396, in realpath
    path, ok = _joinrealpath(filename[:0], filename, strict, {})
  File "/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/anaconda3/envs/inst_crawl/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/anaconda3/envs/inst_crawl/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/.local/lib/python3.10'
```

Which makes me confused because filepath caused the error differ from the path to the specified python interpreter. It is strange to me that VSCode look for the modules at `$HOME/.local/lib` and not at the `$HOME/anaconda3/envs/inst_crawl/lib`, where `inst_crawl` is my conda's environment with all dependencies I need. Ofcourse this env was specified in vscode settings.

My launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug scrapy project",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "program": "/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/anaconda3/envs/inst_crawl/bin/scrapy",
            "args": [
                "crawl",
                "instagram_common_api",
                "-a", "get_user_profile=True",
                "-a", "get_user_stories=True",
                "--logfile", "inst.log",
                "--output", "inst.out.json"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems to me that the problem hiding in Python extension's settings of VSCode, because when i have inspected the `code` variable in the 86 line of runpy.py (see error message behind), I saw that it tries to load depugpy from the python extension:

```
print(code.co_filename)
-> '/home/dmitriy_mikhailov/.vscode-server/extensions/ms-python.python-2023.18.0/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy/adapter/../../debugpy/launcher/../../debugpy/__main__.py'
```

I'm using conda as virtual environment manager and poetry as a package manager inside conda's envs.
So I have tried to solve problem by specifying the right paths to the conda and poetry executables in the Python extension's settings but without any result.

Does anyone has any ideas about possible causes of the problem?

Comment: Forgot to specify an important thing. I'm working with a remote host via ssh connection. Today i've got a physical access to the remote host, and tried to reproduce my problem locally and failed with that: everything work fine.

So, most likely it's connected with some settings of the vscode server, but i still have no idea what it could be and would be glad any help

Comment: To add more details, please [edit] so that the info's all together. [Comments](/help/privileges/comment) are meant to "ask for more information or suggest improvements".